# Text in Tikz Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've been using Tikz and created the following graph with that code :

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=white!60!white,opacity=1] (-2.99,5.98) -- (2.99,5.98) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw [fill=white!30!white,opacity=1,] (0,6) circle (2.99cm and 0.6cm) node [above] {$A_T$};
    \draw [fill=blue!60!white,opacity=1] (-1.49,2.98) -- (1.49,2.98) node [left=1cm, below = 1.5 cm] {\color{blue} $V_0$} -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw [fill=blue!30!white,opacity=1,] (0,3) circle (1.49cm and 0.3cm);
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,3) [line width = 1.3pt] node [left, below = 1cm] {$h_0$};
    \draw (0,3) -- (-1.49, 3) [line width = 1.3pt] node [right = 1cm, above] {$r_0$};
    \draw (3mm,6mm) arc [start angle=50, end angle=126, radius = 5mm, line width = 2pt] node [above = 6pt, right] {$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm really not good at using it and it could be terribly coded. What I've been trying to do is change the text and make it larger so that it's readible. Also I've been trying to position the text for h_0 in the middle and left but it only takes one argument into account. What am I doing wrong?

Could anyone please help me with editing the text?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=white!60!white,opacity=1] (-2.99,5.98) -- (2.99,5.98) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw [fill=white!30!white,opacity=1,] (0,6) circle (2.99cm and 0.6cm) node [above] {$A_T$};
    \draw [fill=blue!60!white,opacity=1] (-1.49,2.98) -- (1.49,2.98) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    \node[font=\color{blue}] at (-0.4,1.7) {$V_0$};
    \draw [fill=blue!30!white,opacity=1,] (0,3) circle (1.49cm and 0.3cm);
    \draw[line width = 1.3pt]  (0,0) -- node[right] {$h_0$} (0,3) -- node[above] {$r_0$} (-1.49, 3)  ;
    \draw (3mm,6mm) arc [start angle=50, end angle=126, radius = 5mm, line width = 2pt] node[near end,above] {$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

If you want to increase the font size, you can pass the option `font=\Large` (or any other font switch) to a node.

[image]

Along a path you can place several nodes and can control the position along the path using several modifiers: `midway`, `near start`, `near end`, `pos=<value>` (there are more possibilities; please refer to the PGF manual):

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (7,6);
\draw 
  (a) -- 
    node[midway] {midway} 
    node[near end] {near end} 
  (b) 
    node[near start] {near start} 
    node[pos=0.333] {pos=0.333};
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (7,6);
\draw 
  (a) -- 
    node[midway,left] {midway, left} 
    node[near end,right] {near end, right} 
  (b) 
    node[near start,below=8pt] {near start,below=8pt} 
    node[pos=0.333,above=6pt] {pos=0.333,above=6pt};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, brilliant answer. Is `pos` a parameter from 0 to 1 along the line?

Comment: @TAllieri You're welcome. If the `<value>` for `pos` is between `0` and `1`, the position lies in the segment joining the two points, If it is greater than one or less then zero, it will lie on the line, but outside the segment.